# vm_mmap crashes work on certain aarch64 platforms

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap, arm64, virtual-memory, pci

Say I have a PCI device with a bar whose address is `0x1f40000000`
I want to map this bar using `vm_mmap()` to user space (from my linux kernel module).
On x86_64 I ran

`addr = vm_mmap(file, 0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 0x1f40000000);`

and received a usable address `addr` that could be used in user mode.
When running this same code from some (not all) aarch64 platforms I get a crash saying I'm accessing the invalid address  `0x8000001f40000000` - but I haven't specified the higher `0x800000` bits anywhere in my code.
Any hints to what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with Linux kernel internals, but it sounds like some layer converts this offset to an address relative to the kernel's half of the address space...

Comment: Can you think of a way to avoid this conversion?

Comment: Nope. But it seems likely that `pgoff` would be converted to a pointer somewhere in architecture-dependent code, so it might be feasible to look for it in src?